# Paypal Payment integration with multiple customers

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

We have multiple customers and many mobile app users. For mobile app users, we need to provide a way to pay to any customer. Please let me know how to achieve this using paypal (or any other global payment gateway)

**Scenario:**

> We have CustomerA, CustomerB etc.,
>
> We have User1, User2, User3 etc.,
>
> Customers can raise invoices to any user.
> When user pays the invoice generated by customer - money should directly go to customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are looking for [PayPal Checkout for Marketplaces and Platforms](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/platforms/checkout/set-up-payments/), note the `payee` variable there.  [This front end](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server) is probably still the best demo code (add the payee variable to purchase_units)

On Mobile, PayPal Checkout must be rendered in a viewer that [has an address bar](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/info-security-guidelines/#secure-applications), such as a Safari View Controller or Chrome Custom Tab. A WKWebView or similar cannot be used.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there any additional charges involved, if we add payee dynamically?

Comment: If you are able to collect the merchant-id from each corresponding user and know which is receiving the payment so as to include it at page load time, the SDK string has a parameter for this: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/customize-sdk/#merchant-id -- but if not, don't.

Comment: Should all merchants have paypal business account?